# How can I put a ViewPager inside a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

My intention is to put a ViewPager with 2 tabs inside a Fragment. If it isn't possible please tell me an alternative... But I would prefer to use ViewPager, because of the swipe effect between tabs.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option #1: Use nested fragments. That will require you to have your `minSdkVersion` set to 17 or higher, or you will have to use the fragments backport from the Android Support Package. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/Nested) demonstrates using the backport.

In short, your fragment that hosts the `ViewPager` will pass `getChildFragmentManager()` to your `FragmentPagerAdapter` or `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2012 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    http://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.pagernested;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class PagerFragment extends Fragment {
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                           ViewGroup container,
                           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View result=inflater.inflate(R.layout.pager, container, false);
    ViewPager pager=(ViewPager)result.findViewById(R.id.pager);

    pager.setAdapter(buildAdapter());

    return(result);
  }

  private PagerAdapter buildAdapter() {
    return(new SampleAdapter(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager()));
  }
}
```

Option #2: Write your own `PagerAdapter` that does not use fragments (or have anything inside of it managed by fragments). Then, you do not need nested fragments anymore, and you can just use your custom `PagerAdapter` with a `ViewPager` that is hosted by a fragment.